# Swift class does not conform to Objective-C protocol with error handling

Tags: objective-c, swift, error-handling, protocols, swift2

I have `Objective-C` Protocol

```
@protocol SomeObjCProtocol
- (BOOL) doSomethingWithError: (NSError **)error;
@end
```

And `Swift` class

```
class SwiftClass : SomeObjCProtocol
{
    func doSomething() throws {    
    }
}
```

Compilers gives me an `error`

> Type 'SwiftClass' does not conform to protocol 'SomeObjCProtocol'"

Is there any solution how to get rid of this error?
I'm using `XCode 7 Beta 4`

Comment: Shouldn't it return a boolean?

Comment: No. Function in Swift class was autocompleted by xcode. Also see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10)

Comment: So you are using Swift 2.0?

Comment: func buyFavoriteSnack(exception: bool) throws


In the implementing class

func buyFavoriteSnack(exception: bool) throws {
    let snackName = favoriteSnacks[person] ?? "Candy Bar"
    try vend(itemNamed: snackName)
}

Or simply refer https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems:

- Swift 2 maps `func doSomething() throws` to the Objective-C method
  `- (BOOL) doSomethingAndReturnError: (NSError **)error;`, which is
  different from your protocol method.
- The protocol method must be marked as "Objective-C compatible" with the `@objc` attribute.

There are two possible solutions:

**Solution 1:** Rename the Objective-C protocol method to

```
@protocol SomeObjCProtocol
- (BOOL) doSomethingAndReturnError: (NSError **)error;
@end
```

**Solution 2:** 
Leave the Objective-C protocol method as it is, and specify the Objective-C mapping for the Swift method
explicitly:

```
@objc(doSomethingWithError:) func doSomething() throws {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Both solutions works. Thank you. Although Solution 1 is a bit weird, because according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10) suffix WithError should work too.

Comment: @Joey: I assume that the rules are slightly different for *protocol* methods. Here the Swift method is mapped to Objective-C (to check the conformance), not the other way around.

Comment: The problem for me was that I misspelled the name of the method in terms of lower and uppercase. Something like: `- (void) thisClass:(Class *)class DidSendStuff:(Stuff *)stuff` and I was trying to work with `- (void) thisClass:(Class *)class didSendStuff:(Stuff *)stuff` **notice the lower and uppercase of DID SEND STUFF**

Answer (score 0):

When encountering that error message, one source of the problem might be that the Swift class conforming to the Objetive C protocol was not inherited from NSObject.